# nodejs errors out when trying to store postgres JSON type

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql

I am trying to store a JSON POST request into a postgresql database. I have defined the profile model to store id as an int, and match_caps as JSON.

profile_model.js

```
db.define('profile', {
  id         : Number,
  match_caps : Object
});
```

Once a POST request has been made I would like to store into postgresql.

profile.js

```
req.on('data', function(chunk){
        data += chunk;
});

req.on('end', function(chunk){ 
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    db.models.profile.create([{
       id         : obj.id,
       match_caps : obj.match_caps
    }], function(err) {//error}
});
```

I am POSTing the following:

```
{"id":101, "match_caps":{"x":1, "y":2}}
```

And I get the following error:

```
error: invalid input syntax for type json
    at Connection.parseE (/home/dev/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:526:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/dev/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:356:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/dev/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:105:22)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
```

I think I am POSTing the JSON correctly. I have tested POSTing the id alone, it was successful.
I have console.log(data), and received the output

```
{"id":101, "match_caps":{"x":1, "y":2}}
```

I have tried to JSON.stringify(obj.match_caps). I recieve the same error.

I am using node ORM to define my models

I am unsure if the POST syntax for match_caps is correct... or if there is a bug in orm.

Comment: Can you `console.log()` or otherwise debug `data` before this `var obj = JSON.parse(data);`?

Comment: Could you indicate which npm module you are using to define your models?

Comment: I have console.log(data)... and received the same JSON format I had POSTed. I have updated my first post.

Comment: I have updated post to indicate that I am using Node ORM to define my models.

Comment: Try `var obj = data;` instead `var obj = JSON.parse(data);` ? `data` might already be an object?

Comment: OK, so you can be sure your POST syntax is fine. If there was anything wrong, this line would throw an exception, and it isn't, so no problem there. `var obj = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Ah, you're right Peter.